# C++ swapping function

Tags: c++11, c++14

Why doesn't my function influence the original vector I passed in `main()`?

```
void swap2(int &x, int &y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;

}

void reverse_2(vector<int> &v1)
{
    int j = v1.size() - 1;
    cout << j << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i != v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        swap2(v1[i], v1[j]);
        j--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int>i1 = { 1,3,5,7,9 }, i2(i1.size());
    i2 = reverse_1(i1);
    for (int i = 0; i != i1.size(); ++i)
    {
        //cout << "First array"<<i1[i] << ","<<endl;
        //cout << "Second array" << i2[i] << "," << endl;
    }
    reverse_2(i1);
    cout << "First array changed" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i != i1.size(); ++i)
        cout << i1[i] << ",";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inverting every element in your vector twice.

The first time you put say `0` to `n-1`, then when you hit `i=n-1`, you swap them back...

```
for (int i = 0; i < i1.size() / 2; ++i)
```

Comment: For me this gives a nice compile warning (comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions) which can be avoided as follows: `for (int i = 0, n = size(i1) / 2; i < n; ++i)`

Comment: The propet way of fixing it is to use either `size_t` or a `static_cast` with `gsl::index`.